# How can i check if php system function executes wihtout any error?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $command = "mysqldump -uroot -ppassword test --compact --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --extended-insert=FALSE --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --routines --databases --triggers | gzip > test.sql.gz ";
    system ( $command );
?>
```

How to check if it executes without errors??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94929

Comment: how about `restore_error_handler();`

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = system ( $command , $return_var )
```

If the $return_var argument is present, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

$output returns the last line of the command output on success.

You can learn from [system function PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

Comment: Thanks @TarunBhati

Comment: here the return_var is always empty either the command executed or not

Answer (score 1):

It returns a String with the resolution, so try this:

```
$output = system ( $command );
if ($output == FALSE) { echo "error"; } else { echo $output; }
```

Comment: if i run the command it echos an error for both correct and wrong scenarios.

Comment: All right, if you run the command in the command line, does it throw a message if it works?

Comment: it does not throw any message

Comment: Then the problem will probably be in the command... as the PHP doc says, system function "Returns the last line of the command output on success, and FALSE on failure."

Comment: If the command does not output anything, how do you want to check the errors?